# The latest version of maven is not installed in Ubuntu

Tags: maven, ubuntu, java-17

I can't execute the command

```bash
mvn clean install
```

> [ERROR] Error executing Maven.
> [ERROR] java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load cache item
> [ERROR] Caused by: Unable to load cache item
> [ERROR] Caused by: Could not initialize class com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$MethodWrapper

and other similar commands, since the project is in java 17.

I was trying to install the latest version of maven:

[image]

```bash
java --version

openjdk 17.0.3 2022-04-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.3+7-Ubuntu-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.3+7-Ubuntu-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, mixed mode, sharing)
```

```bash
 which java
/usr/bin/java
```

```bash
mkdir -p tmp
```

```bash
TMP_MAVEN_VERSION=3.8.5
```

```bash
wget -P ~/tmp/ https://dlcdn.apache.org/maven/maven-3/3.8.5/binaries/apache-maven-$TMP_MAVEN_VERSION-bin.tar.gz
```

```bash
sudo tar xf  ~/tmp/apache-maven-*.tar.gz -C /opt 
sudo rm  ~/tmp/apache-maven-*-bin.tar.gz
```

```bash
sudo ln -s /opt/apache-maven-$TMP_MAVEN_VERSION /opt/maven
```

```bash
sudo touch /etc/profile.d/maven.sh
```

Change owner

```bash
sudo chown user  /etc/profile.d/maven.sh
```

Add to file

```bash
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.17.0-openjdk-amd64
export M2_HOME=/opt/maven
export MAVEN_HOME=/opt/maven
export PATH=$M2_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

```bash
sudo chmod +x /etc/profile.d/maven.sh 
source /etc/profile.d/maven.sh
```

```bash
mvn -v
```

An error appears

> /opt/maven/bin/mvn: 1: uname: not found
> /opt/maven/bin/mvn: 1: dirname: not found
> Error: Could not find or load main class org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher

I close the terminal and open it again

```bash
Apache Maven 3.6.3
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 17.0.3, vendor: Private Build, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "5.13.0-44-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

I need the latest version package in the system.

Maybe who knows how to fix this problem?

Comment: First this: `mvn build` does not exist. You should try `mvn clean` for example or just to check if it's installed `mvn --version`... second you should add `/opt/maven/bin` to your path like this: `export PATH=/opt/maven/bin:$PATH` after this try `mvn --version` also the `JAVA_HOME` is needed...

Comment: The maven is installed, but the younger version

Comment: You mean Maven 3.8.5 ?

Comment: It's that. I want to install maven 3.8.5

Comment: Ah Ok.. thats fine ...the most recent version very good.

Comment: @khmarbaise. so how can this task be solved ?

Comment: so `mvn --version` shows exactly what?

Comment: I indicated this in the message above

Comment: Really something like: `Apache Maven 3.8.4 (9b656c72d54e5bacbed989b64718c159fe39b537)` (of course 3.8.5 and different)?

Comment: So retry to build your whole project...

Comment: How Old is this Ubuntu?

Comment: It is Ubuntu 20.x

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this:

to correct that (/etc/profile.d/maven.sh):

```bash
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64
export M2_HOME=/opt/maven
export MAVEN_HOME=/opt/maven
export PATH=$M2_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

and to perform

```bash
source /etc/profile.d/maven.sh
```

Comment: THis answer is outdated. Not working anymore on docker container `bash: /etc/profile.d/maven.sh: No such file or directory`